# C# / Asp.NET: Is there an advantage to setting data in ViewData/ViewBag every request vs calling an action method to get the data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to display a user's profile image in my _Layout.cshtml but not sure if I should set the file path every request in the ViewBag/ViewData or create an action method that returns the file path. Are there any performance considerations between the two approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you set the data in the ViewBag / ViewData, this data is processed while your page is being generated.  If you create a dedicated action method, that would mean just one extra request to the web-server.  Since the path is short and the associated data is tiny, calling the extra controller method should be slightly slower.

Comment: Okay makes sense to me. I'll give that a try, thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
public class GlobalViewBagFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
       filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.UserImage = "Your Image Path";
    }
}
```

Add it in FilterConfig on App_start Folder

```
 public class FilterConfig
 {
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
       filters.Add(new GlobalViewBagFilter ());
    }
  }
```

Now you can get ViewBag.UserImage _Layout in your application.